Oracle APEX Interactive Grid Row Revert using Javascript
I am trying to revert interactive grid rows using JavaScript API in dynamic action. (Based on some conditions).
apex.region("PRODS").call("getActions").invoke("row-revert");

apex.region("PRODS").call("getActions").invoke("selection-revert");

It does not work initially, but if I select another row and then select the row I want to revert and then run this code manually in the console it reverts the row changes.
Can anybody please tell what could be the solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance.

This answer may be a little late, but you have to invoke a refresh on your selection.
This is what happens if you select another row and go back to your row.
You need to invoke the following action:
apex.region("PRODS").call("getActions").invoke("selection-refresh");

